# Sort an array by its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array.

```
var arr = ["1-5", "3-6", "2-4"];
```

Is there a way where I can sort like this:

```
var arr = ["1-5", "2-4", "3-6"]
```

I've tried with jquery map but cant because the values of array are not Numbers.

Comment: Is it just ordered by the first number? Can you show what you have so far, as it could be helpful to show where you went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

Sort by *first* number

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {

  //  a.split('-') - split a string into an array  - ['1', '5']
  //  a.split('-')[0] - get first element          - '1' 
  // "+" converts string to number                 - 1
  // the same for "b"

  return +a.split('-')[0] - +b.split('-')[0]; 
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hologu/1/edit?js,console)

Sort by *second* number

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return +a.split('-')[1] - +b.split('-')[1];
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hologu/4/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Use array sort. First the first num is compared. If they are equal, the second num is compared..

```js
var arr = ["1-5", "3-6", "2-4"];
    
var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){
       var numsA = a.split('-');
       var numsB = b.split('-');
       if (numsA[0]-numsB[0] !== 0){
           return numsA[0] - numsB[0];
       }
       return numsA[1] - numsB[1];
});
    
document.write(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built in sort functionality `arr.sort()`

http://jsfiddle.net/qctg9cfx/

Answer (score 0):

If sorting by the first number in the string, and also if the first number could itself be negative then a more robust solution may be to use `parseInt`.

```js
var arr = ["1-5", "3-6", "-1-3", "2-4"];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```